# Get a CheckBox to command a GridView row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have a `GridView` holding my order table (these are inserted values from an insert statement). The order table appears on the doctor page, but I want to add to it so it can be approve/unapproved (if checked then update the 'Approve' column to approved, if not checked update the 'Approve' column to not approved. I need to add a `CheckBox` column to the `GridView` for this. This is part of my learning (not a live website).

How do I add a column of check boxes to a `GridView` that would set a row to approve/unapproved when checked?

This is my order table -(all the data is dummy data)

[image: order table]

Grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewdoc" runat="server"  >
</asp:GridView>
```

Showing the data on the grid

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Dim cmd3string As String = " Select * From alltheview  WHERE DoctorId = " & Session("DoctorId")
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd3string, conn)
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()

        GridViewdoc.DataSource = dt
        GridViewdoc.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

My select statement that pulls the data:

```
Create View theallview 
As 

Select A.OrderID
  ,A.PatientId ,B.Forename,B.Surname ,A.MedicineId   ,C.Name      as   MedicineName ,E.Name as DoctorName, A.PharmacyId  ,D.pharmname  ,A.DoctorId ,A.Dateordered, Approved
From  order_pres  A
 Left  Join Patient   B on (A.PatientId  = B.PatientId)
 Left  Join Medicine  C on (A.MedicineId = C.MedicineId)
 Left  Join pharmacy  D on (A.PharmacyId   = D.PharmacyId)
 Left  Join Doctor    E on (A.DoctorId  = E.DoctorId)
```

How the order table now looks (this is all dummy data by the way:

A button . click event will then submit the checked values
If anyone needs more information regarding this question please let me know.

Comment: Your DB field "Approved" is `varchar(50)`. Is that the field you want to use as a source for the column? If so, it should really be of bit type

Comment: Hi @Andrei - This is the column I want to update to approve if checked and not approved if not checked

Comment: So is there any specific reason why you want it to be a string column? Really, bit makes a lot more sense here (this is basically boolean), and besides your grid view column will just work out of the box

Comment: Hi @Andrei - what way would you think is best to do this? In the answer below when I try to apply a check box column to the gridview I am getting errors

Comment: Because answer below assumes the Db column is a bit/boolean, and it is not. It should be, really, this is the way to do it if you asked my opinion. Infomation you need to store there is binary either approved or not, and this is exactly what booleans are for

Comment: So change approve to bit in my database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116388/discussion-between-laurajs-and-andrei).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's in C# but you should be able to work out the VB.Net pretty easily.

As an aside I would put your code to load your data in its own method. Once the approved is updated I would recommend reloading your grid view.

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewdoc" DataKeyNames="OrderId" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Order Id" DataField="OrderId" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Patient Id" DataField="PatientId" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Medicine Id" DataField="MedicineId" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Pharmacy Id" DataField="PharmacyId" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Doctor Id" DataField="DoctorId" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Date Ordered" DataField="Dateordered" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve/Unapprove">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApproved" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# Eval("Approved") == null || Eval("Approved") == DBNull.Value ? false : Eval("Approved") %>' runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkApproved_CheckedChanged" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void chkApproved_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkApproved = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow gridViewRow = (GridViewRow)chkApproved.Parent.Parent;
    int orderID = (int)GridViewdoc.DataKeys[gridViewRow.RowIndex].Value;
    bool approved = chkApproved.Checked;

    //Your update method
    UpdateApproved(orderID, approved);
    //Your data load method
    LoadData();
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael - thankyou for your answer. When I apply this to my gridview (without the behind code)  and try to open the page (it showed the grid before) - I now get the following error  - 
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 1.

Comment: You need the code behind in place or the code will error. If you want to run just the aspx portion remove the:

    OnCheckedChanged="chkApproved_CheckedChanged"

Comment: Michael, thankyou for this help :)  so I took this out but I was still getting an error under `Checked='<%# Eval("Approved") %>' `  it is saying Additional information: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Boolean' is not valid.  - When I removed that the only thing in the grid that came up was the check boxes and did not join the rest of the grid that normally appears.

Comment: I have changed to bit but when trying to load the page now under checked '<%# Eval ("Approved") %> I am getting - Additional information: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Boolean' is not valid.    @Andrei

Comment: I added some additional code to my answer that should resolve the DBNull issue. I also added an examples of how to include the other columns. When using the gridview, the property AutoGenerateColumns is set to true by default. In my code this was set to "false" to allow for better handling of the checkbox. Putting code inline like this is a terrible way of managing the data. Code behind is always the way to go if you have a lot of processing to do.